# Django destroy and keep newly created testing database

Tags: django, django-testing

I know we could use `--keepdb` when running `manage.py test` to keep the test databases, but when i have a new migration, the old DB need to be destroyed to create new one. Is there any way to destroy the old DB AND keep it after test completed ?

Comment: Any unapplied migrations will be applied when you run your tests even if you keep the DB. Are you talking about deleting a migration file and creating a new migration causing you to need to delete the DB?

Comment: No, the case is: I have old testing DB --> I have new migration, and i need to test it thus destroying old testing DB --> I want to newly created testing DB not destroyed after i run testing

Edit: Oh, unapplied migrations will be applied on next test run even with `keepdb` ?

Comment: Yes, unapplied migrations will be applied on next test run even with keepdb - `Unless the MIGRATE test setting is False, any unapplied migrations will also be applied to the test database before running the test suite.` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-keepdb